# Switching from Deploy to Key to User Key in private Travis-CI

Tags: travis-ci, ssh-keys

Private Travis-CI is used in our organisation to run builds and CRON jobs on a private GitHub repo. Currently a Deploy key is set to access the private GitHub repo. Now it is necessary to clone another private repo from the same organisation in `.travis.yml` script. The easiest and recommended way is to switch to User Key, i.e., use a GitHub user, which has access to all required repo.

I have uploaded the SSH key for the user, who has access to both repos, using CLI command of Travis-CI as described in [the documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/#reusing-a-generated-key) for both private repos. However, I get error that the cloning repo is not found.

The script contains a line similar to:

```
- git clone --progress --verbose git@github.com:organisation/another-git-repo.git /tmp/local-folder
```

The error message is:

> ERROR: Repository not found.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

The test, which gets the error message, is done by submitting changes into `.travis.yml`, which is part of the repo, with the git clone command in the fork of the repo.

What can be the issue?

So I am guessing I need to drop the Deploy key, so the User key is used, but I don't find anything in Travis-CI documentation. Since the builds are actively used by developers, I want to be sure that dropping Deploy key is the way forward. Can anyone confirm that dropping Deploy key is necessary to make CLI uploaded User key to work?

Also I don't find in Travis-CI documentation: how can I see that the user key was uploaded to be used with repos?

Comment: Found answer to last question: use `travis pubkey -r <owner>/<repo>`

Comment: Also the answer to the first question: deploy key is automatically replaces with user key, so no need to delete it. Still the error is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answers to my questions.

> Can anyone confirm that dropping Deploy key is necessary to make CLI uploaded User key to work?

Yes, when User key is uploaded, it replaces Deploy key. As result, in GUI of Travis-CI the SSH key will have name of the User key, which was specified during upload through command line. In the [Travis-CI doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/#using-an-existing-key) it is called `Default`.

> Also I don't find in Travis-CI documentation: how can I see that the user key was uploaded to be used with repos?

In addition to observing keys in Travis-CI GUI for each repo, it can be checked by using command line:

```sh
travis pubkey -r <owner>/<repo>
```

The public key will be the same for different repos if it was uploaded to them.

> What can be the issue?

First, it is good to check if the SSH key of the user works to authenticate to GitHub. It is likely that the default user is different from this user to test. One way is to test is to clean SSH agent and add the other user:

```sh
ssh-add -D
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_travis_rsa
```

As extra, SSH keys of the default local user can be temporary removed/renamed in `.ssh` folder, so they will not participate in the test.
Then test authentication with GitHub in verbose mode:

```sh
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

Note if it succeeds, it will print the user name from global git configuration, not the user, who was actually authenticated through the key.
Now it is good to clone interesting repos to double check if read permissions are given.

If everything succeeds, then it is expected to work. Another way to test with Travis-CI is to add temporary the git clone command as `before_script` to a job in `.travis.yml`, which is always executed on pull request, and create a pull request. This works better than using a special purpose branch.

```
before_script:
  - git clone --progress --verbose git@github.com:<owner>/<repo>.git tmp/<repo>
```